# The killing vectors of flat space in polar coordinates

Tags: metric-spaces, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates, symmetry, general-relativity

The metric of flat three-dimensional space is written in usual Cartesian coordinates

```
  ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2
```

There are 3 killing vectors (1,0,0) , (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) that corresponds to three translational symmetries of flat space.

But when the polar coordinates are used

ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2 d theta^2 + r^2sin^2 theta d phi^2

The killing vectors of this polar metric is (0,0,1) in polar coordinates but (-y,x,0) in Cartesian coordinates

Can someone please explain how do we get (-y,x,0) ???

Comment: I don't think it's easy to read off the translational symmetries $\partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z$ in spherical coordinates, though you can read off immediately that $\partial_\phi$ is a (rotational) symmetry. The easiest method might be to push forward the translations $\partial_{x^i}$ by the identity map converting from Cartesian to spherical coordinates, e.g., $\partial_z = \cos \theta \, \partial_r - \frac{\sin \theta}{r} \partial_\theta$.

Comment: What should be the angle theta??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question in the comments. In the original question, do you mean, how do we compute that $-y \partial_x + x \partial_y$ is a Killing field? Or do you mean, how do we rewrite the vector field $\partial_\phi$ in rectangular coordinates?

Comment: consider line element in polar coordinates: there is a rotational symmetry because we can take phi as a constant due to which killing vector is (0,0,1) in polar form
My question is how to get this vector in Cartesian form which should be (-y,x0)

Comment: Do you mean, how do we convert $(0, 0, 1)_{\rm spherical}$ to the Cartesian representation $(-y, x, 0)_{\rm Cartesian}$? That amounts to pushing forward by the identity map written with respect to those coordinates; is it the details of that computation that you'd like to see?

Comment: Yes. I want to see that working

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant, but there are six Killing vectors in flat $\mathbb{R}^3$: three translations and three rotations. The co-ordinate system doesn't affect this counting but it will affect what the components of the Killing vectors look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to approach the computation. One typical method is to push forward the coordinate vector field $\partial_\phi$ by the coordinate transformation formula, i.e., the identity map $\operatorname{id}$ written in its coordinate representation:
\begin{align*}
x &= r \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
y &= r \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
z &= r \cos \theta .
\end{align*}

Computing the relevant components, $\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial \phi}$, of the matrix representation of the tangent map (i.e., the Jacobian matrix), gives
$$[T \operatorname{id}]
= \pmatrix{
* & * & -r \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
* & * & r \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
* & * & 0 } .
$$
So, the matrix representation of $\partial_\phi$ with respect to the Cartesian coordinate frame is
$$[T \operatorname{id}] [\partial_\phi] = \pmatrix{
* & * & -r \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
* & * &  r \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
* & * &  0 }
\pmatrix{0\\0\\1} = \pmatrix{
-r \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
 r \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
 0 } .$$
Thus, as an explicit linear combination of the Cartesian coordinate vector fields, $\partial_\phi$ is
$$\partial_\phi = (- r \sin \theta \sin \phi) \partial_x + (r \sin \theta \cos \phi) \partial_y + (0) \partial_z = \boxed{-y \partial_x + x \partial_y} .$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't try with this approach. Now it makes sense